# How did Catherine Weaver (T-1001) stop an explosion fire?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-sarah-connor-chronicles

In the last episode of *Terminator: The Sarah Connor Chronicles* TV series, [Catherine Weaver](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Catherine_Weaver) protected Sarah Connor, John Connor & James Ellison by stopping an explosion fire with her expanded body.

[image: Catherine Weaver stopping explosion - Get Down]

How could a T-1001 model do that when in the same series it was shown that bullets were making temporary holes in her body? How does this Claytronics mechanism work?

Comment: *"stopping an explosion fire"*  Do you have a screen-shot?  To stop an explosion proceeding along an enclosed space (e.g a corridor, air-duct or tunnel) would be almost impossible, but to deflect one around key objects in an open space is much easier.

Comment: @Andrew Deflecting in open space can only be easier if the object is strong enough.

Comment: An explosion is a broad pressure wave of expanding gases propagating through the air, while a bullet imparts kinetic energy in a very focused point. This makes the bullet better at *penetrating*, while the blast wave by itself simply tends to shove and throw things about (unless it is laden with shrapnel, that is).

Comment: *"..if the object is strong enough"*  While true, it is also relatively meaningless.  Tissue paper would not be strong enough, a party balloon would not be strong enough, a soap bubble would not be strong enough, ..but a thin sheet of tin might be strong enough.  ***Do you have a screen-shot?***

Comment: @AndrewThompson Got the screenshot from Wikia... added to question..

Comment: Yeah, that deflection actually looks pretty plausible to me.  It is mostly a fire-ball rather than a traditional 'bang' explosion.  Note the fire does seem to be curling over the top a bit, so it is not as though the T-1000 was actually completely 'containing' the blast.  +1 for the image.

Answer (score 7):

We never saw Weaver stop anything that looked like an explosion, i.e. something involving a detonation and shock wave.  She shielded the Connors and Ellison from a mild fuel deflagration and debris from some kind of drone crashing through the window.  She then said "Run!" and the humans dashed out into the hallway.  Only then did we hear a series of larger concussions that might have been explosions, but the humans had put some distance between themselves and the inferno by then.

Comment: You're turning down the screenshot by hand. Right?

Comment: I rewatched the episode.  That was no explosion.